# Is it possible to install OpenOffice and LibreOffice in parallel?

Tags: libreoffice, versions, openoffice.org

Because of [this bug](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/18743/scrolling-and-display-problem-bug-in-libreoffice-36-and-above/) I was forced to use an older version of LibreOffice.

But I would like to have the latest LibreOffice - keeping in this way an eye on a possible future fix to the bug.

And,  when I need to avoid this bug, I would like to install in parallel a version of OpenOffice which is not affected by the bug (e.g 3.4)

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you think that they would be incompatible?

Comment: @minerz029 - i thought i heard that to install one the other should be removed...

Comment: I think that you should just try `sudo apt-get install openoffice` and see if that errors (or offers to remove libreoffice)

Comment: @minerz029 - already have oo 3.4. so, i will install latest LO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong to have OpenOffice and LibreOffice installed at the same time. Moreover, you can have more than one version of  OpenOffice and more than one version of LibreOffice without any conflict.

[**LibreOffice**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libreoffice/) can be found in the Ubuntu Software Center. If you want the latest version, you can find it at http://www.libreoffice.org/download/.

To install **OpenOffice** (now known as **Apache OpenOffice**), open the terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/office
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openoffice
```

<sub>Source: [How To Install Apache OpenOffice 3.4 Via PPA On Ubuntu](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/05/how-to-install-apache-openoffice-34-via.html)</sub>

Comment: this doesn't work on Trusty: Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support trusty''

Answer (score 0):

Actually it cannot be done by simply install via apt or by running dpkg with the program install files.

When installing, both programs write the `soffice` core program link in `/usr/bin/`. This conflict prevents both programs from installation in Ubuntu. You will get an error trying to overwrite `/usr/bin/soffice`.

Comment: i have installed both, latest libreoffice from sources and oo 3.4 from deb - without errors

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but, I looked for this answer and figured it out on Ubuntu 18.04

- If Libreoffice is already installed, uninstall it from terminal:

sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice*

- Download the DEB files for both Libreoffice and Open office
  http://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html
- Expand the openoffice debs files (in gnome, just double click them and drag them to the desktp for instance), navigate to the DEBS folder and enter the following from terminal:

  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
- Navigate to the desktop integration folder and issue the same command as you did in #3
- Now, do the same with libre office
  https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/

It seems that Libre Office adds a link to the system which does not let you install Open Office.  But if you install Open Office first, then it seems to work.